# Python class mutual static (class) variables

Tags: python, oop, class, static-variables

In Python, if I have something like:

```
class A(object):
    b = B()


class B(object):
   a = A()
```

Will produce an error `NameError: name 'B' is not defined`

How would you elegantly resolve this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
class B(object):
    pass

class A(object):
    b = B()

B.a = A()
```

Comment: if B has another static member, it cannot be accessed from A.b.another_stativ_var . I would have liked to have the other static members defined inside the class.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters Yes you can. My mistake. Thank you!